# How do you hide code based on macro definition?

Tags: xcode, macros

With VisualStudio/Resharper we get a useful feature which hides code (or turns it to another color) based on macro definition. For example:

```
#ifdef DEBUG

if(!is_DEBUG_defined)
{
   // Make code gray
   // Or hide it!
}

#endif
```

Is there any way to have this behaviour in XCode? I noticed that in this case any variable/function defined inside the `#ifdef`/`#endif` statements is not available outside in XCode's autocomplete if the macro is not defined but it would be very useful if there was also a visual indication that that code is not actually going to be compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Xcode already does this - but it's hard to see on some Themes.
With the default theme, the source code of non-pre-processed sections is plain black.

Change your theme temporarily to "Dusk" (Xcode->Preferences->Fonts&Colors),
and then code of non-pre-processed sections will be in plain white, which is much easier to see.

Comment: I can't agree with that. OK, Xcode already does this but not fully. Keywords, type declarations or Strings are still in colours. The solution would be if xCode change inactive code to plain text. But I don't know how to do that?

Comment: Did they break this in Xcode 11.6? I no longer see any difference in the code color, regardless of which theme I pick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes same code is worhing in `objective c` also. Like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   //your code
#endif
```